# Insert a div every three items in the wordpress loop (php)

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I am trying to add an image after every three posts in the wordpress loop. Here's the loop:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

  <?php /* The loop */ ?>
  <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
  <?php endwhile; ?>

  <?php twentythirteen_paging_nav(); ?>

<?php else : ?>
  <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

My guess would be to insert a counter, but I'm not sure about the placement. My guess.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
  <?php $counter = 0; ?>     
  <?php /* The loop */ ?>
  <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <?php $counter++; ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
  <?php if ($counter == 3) echo '<img src="url-to-img.jpg" alt="img">'; ?>
  <?php endwhile; ?>

  <?php twentythirteen_paging_nav(); ?>

<?php else : ?>
  <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But even if this would work (not tested), the counter should reset after the image has been inserted. How should you do that?

**Summary**: insert an image after every three posts.

Comment: Either reset the counter yourself, or make use of the mod operator (%) `if (($counter %3) == 0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need the modulo operator. Instead of doing `if ($counter == 3)`, which checks if the counter is three, you should do `if ($counter % 3 == 0)`, which checks whether $counter is evenly divisible by three.

Comment: Note: If you use modulo (recommended), you never need to reset the counter.